# Translating Jade to Javascript

Tags: pug

I'm translating a Jade script line, just wanted to double check I have it right. Are these two doing the same logic?

Jade:

```
  if !!bootstrappedUser
    script.
        window.bootstrappedUserObject = !{JSON.stringify(bootstrappedUser)}
```

JS:

```
 if (bootstrappedUser != "undefined"){
   window.bootstrappedUserObject = JSON.stringify(bootstrappedUser);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the function with create when you run this code in jade

```
function anonymous(locals) {
  var buf = [];
  with (locals || {}) {
      if(!!bootstrappedUser){
        buf.push('<script type="text/javascript">');
        buf.push('window.bootstrappedUserObject = ');
        buf.push('' + JSON.stringify(bootstrappedUser) + '');
        buf.push('</script>');
      }

    }  
  }
  return buf.join("");
}
```